# All cv2 functions are not found

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

I have pip installed opencv-python on my Ubuntu guest OS hosted in a virtual box. Both my python and Ubuntu are 64-bit. But when I import cv2 I couldn't find all the functions to manipulate images. The following is an image of the *ini* file I get when I do ctrl+B. 
[image]
I uninstalled the opencv and followed many tutorials to install opencv using apt-get including from the official opencv website and none of them worked for me. Can someone give me a hint what I can do to get opencv to work?

Comment: You haven't explained what you tried and what is not working. What functions are you trying to import? What happened when you tried? What does that graphic of an init file have to do with anything?

Comment: cv2.VideoCapture(), cv2.VideoWriter, cv2.imShow().... are not found. My IDE is Pycharm just for the record.

Comment: I should finally consider quitting using this website. There are a lot of immature, 12 year old children who love downvoting without any explanation whatsoever. Complete nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [this tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/), I was able to finally install opencv properly. I am posting my answer to help someone in a similar situation. Ubuntu version is the most important thing you have to check before you follow any of the tutorials. Just like my case, if you happen to follow one of the old tutorials but your Ubuntu version is 16, you need to remove the opencv altogether then follow the tutorial. 
After the fix, my *ini* looks like this. It consists all the functions to manipulate image. The screenshot shows the partial shot in my ide.

[image]